# ViewModels with OData WebAPI Doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get View Model result from WebAPI using OData. I am trying it with simple example. I have created 2 View Models (Menu, MenuItems) and OdatController for each of View Model.
I created 2 View Model classes Menu and MenuItems and OData controller for each of the View Model Class. Also added EntitySet code in WebApiConfig class.

```
public class Menu
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<MenuItems> MenuItems { get; set; }
}

public class MenuItems {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MenuID { get; set; }
}
```

In Menus Controller, GetMenus() i am populating Menus with sample data and each menu contains Menu items. When i run the API and enter the following URL odata/Menus?$expand=MenuItems It only displays JSON Menus list. 
am i missing anything?